# Puppeteer click submit button and open new tab

Tags: javascript, button, puppeteer

I would like to click on submit button and open in new tab then **scrape** the page and close it. Because it is a submit button I can not see the link. How can I click and open the generated page in a new tab?

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" name="find" class="button-with-caret" id="find_button" value="find">Search</button>
```

I'm thinking about something like this:

```
      try {
        await page.evaluate((selector) => {
          return document.querySelector(selector).click();
        }, '#find_button');
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
```